# Method and Variable Scope Issue in Java

Tags: java, scope, method-declaration

I need help I cannot figure out how to fix the scope of my variables. I want this to be an example for my notes but have been on it for almost 2 hours.

```
public class methodPractice{
    String streetName;
    int streetNum;
        public static void streetName()
    { 
         String streetName = "Pope Ave.";
    }
        public static void streetNum()
    {
        int streetNum = 11825;
    }
        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        streetName();
        streetNum();
        System.out.println("This is your home adress: " + streetNum + 
        streetName);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Title is vague.

Answer (score 1):

You are [***shadowing***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the fields. Use `this` to make sure you get the fields, or a compile error.

```
public static void streetName()
{ 
    this.streetName = "Pope Ave.";
}

public static void streetNum()
{
    this.streetNum = 11825;
}
```

Comment: Compiler error, you called non-static members from static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your `main` method, with line numbers added:

```
1.    public static void main(String[] args) {
2.       streetName();
3.       streetNum();
4.       System.out.println("This is your home adress: " + streetNum + streetName);
5.    }
```

A few points...

- When line 2 runs, "streetName()" calls the static method below. The `static` keyword says you are free to call the method by itself – that is, you don't need an object; you don't need to call `new methodPractice()` first.

  ```
  public static void streetName() {
      String streetName = "Pope Ave.";
  }
  ```
- When line 3 runs, it's the same thing: "streetNum()" calls a different static method – again, totally fine to call this by itself.

  ```
  public static void streetNum() {
      int streetNum = 11825;
  }
  ```
- Line 4 is different, there are a few things going on. Your expectation is that "streetNum" finds the `int` that you declared on the class, but it doesn't work. Why? Because you defined that member with "int streetNum" – without "static". So what? Without being declared static, it means "streetNum" belongs to an *object instance*. What does that look like? Here's an example showing object creation, followed by setting the object member "streetNum" to 1.

  ```
  methodPractice object = new methodPractice();
  object.streetNum = 1;
  ```

You could work around this by declaring both of the non-static members to be static (`static String streetName`, and `static int streetNum`). Or you could leave them as is, and interact with them through an object instance (after doing `new ..`).